# How SATA SSD drives get mapped to /dev/sd<letter>?

Tags: ssd, sata

Is there a way to specify that new SSD drives gets mapped to /dev/sdc or /dev/sdd? Or is this out of my control and the kernal will just assign the next unused letter in the sequence?

Comment: Possibly related: [How are /dev/sda and /dev/sdb chosen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371049/how-are-dev-sda-and-dev-sdb-chosen)

Comment: I find order is set by SATA port number. So I start with SATA0. But even that does not always work as some of my systems will promote a flash drive or other USB drive to be hd0 in grub. Sometimes also flash drive becomes sda, changing all the other drives.

Comment: This seems very much like a possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377). Why does the drive label matter?

Answer (score 2):

As you say, the kernal will simply add the next unused letter in the sequence.

I think that it is quite dangerous to refer to disks by /dev/sdX because X can change (eg sdc might become sdb if sdb isn't available when you boot), this could do a lot of damage if (say) you used sdb for swap and sdc for critical data.

You are a lot safer to refer to disks by references in `/dev/disk/by-id`. If you have a look in this directory you will see a list of drive references that the kernel automatically links to the correct /dev/sdX. If X changes, the kernel changes the link (see example below)

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jul  8 08:02 ata-TOSHIBA_HDWE160_X7HOK1HIF56D -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul  8 08:02 ata-TOSHIBA_HDWE160_X7HOK1HIF56D-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jul  8 08:02 ata-WDC_WD60EZRZ-00GZ5B1_WD-WX21D55336XF -> ../../sda
```